# How to manage JMS Serializer serialization rules

Tags: php, xml, serialization, xsd, jms-serializer

I am using [xsd2php](https://github.com/goetas-webservices/xsd2php) library to parse XSD which describes API request body. Then using the same library (which itself uses [jsm-serializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer)) I try to serialize objects:

```
$payload = new TrackRequest;

$searchCriteria = new SearchCriteriaAType;
$searchCriteria->addToConsignmentNumber(11111);
$payload->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);

$levelOfDetail = new LevelOfDetailAType;
$levelOfDetail->setSummary(true);
$payload->setLevelOfDetail($levelOfDetail);
```

Using basic serializer settings:

```
$serializerBuilder = SerializerBuilder::create();
$serializerBuilder->addMetadataDir(__DIR__ . '/../../metadata/Tracking', 'TNTExpressConnect\Tracking\XSD');
$serializerBuilder->setPropertyNamingStrategy(new IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy);
$serializerBuilder->configureHandlers(function (HandlerRegistryInterface $handler) use ($serializerBuilder) {
    $serializerBuilder->addDefaultHandlers();
    $handler->registerSubscribingHandler(new BaseTypesHandler()); // XMLSchema List handling
    $handler->registerSubscribingHandler(new XmlSchemaDateHandler()); // XMLSchema date handling
});
```

Serialization results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <searchCriteria>
    <account/>
    <alternativeConsignmentNumber/>
    <consignmentNumber>
      <entry><![CDATA[11111]]></entry>
    </consignmentNumber>
    <customerReference/>
    <pieceReference/>
  </searchCriteria>
  <levelOfDetail>
    <summary>true</summary>
  </levelOfDetail>
</result>
```

Regarding this results I have several questions:

1. Why the root element is `<result>` and not `<TrackRequest>`?
2. How to get rid of `CDATA`?
3. How to get rid of `<entry>` tags in favor of creating separate `consigmentNumber` tag for each entry?
4. How to replace `<summary>true</summary>` with self-closing tag `<summary/>`

I guess for every one of this cases I can create a dedicated [handler](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers), but maybe there is a built-in solution, which I overlooked in the documentation (maybe some config options that can be placed in yaml).

And if I have to create handlers maybe someone can point me the more sophisticated example, that explains how to do it right.

I'm not a big fan of annotations, so I would prefer to use separate config files.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look ar the [YAML Reference](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference). A lot of things can be set up with the meta data files.

1. To change the "result" to "TrackRequest" add this line to the file:

   ```
   Vendor\MyBundle\Model\ClassName:
       xml_root_name: TrackRequest ## Changes the root element
   ```
2. To get rid of cdata in entry change the property:

   ```
   properties:
   entry:
       xml_element:
           cdata: false ## Add this to disable cdata tags
   ```

Just came accross the same problems as you did. I hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, a small update about the root elements.
It was not necessary to set `xml_root_name` option, in my case I was creating an partial XML object, probably you should check if there are any parent objects where you could put your `TrackRequest` object (probably some Message object, so not `[root]->TrackRequest` but `[root]->Message->TrackRequest`. The root naming shouldn't be a problem then.